# De Moivre's use to a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

I have this question which I'm stuck on, here's the question and what I did.

Find the smallest positive integer m such that $\left(\sqrt{3}+i\right)^m=\left(\sqrt{3}-i\right)^m$.

I expanded out each side using De Moivre's, $\cos\left(30m\right)+i\sin\left(30m\right)=\cos\left(-30m\right)+i\sin\left(-30m\right)$.

I tried to compare when $\cos\left(30m\right)=\cos\left(-30m\right)$ and $\sin\left(30m\right)=\sin\left(-30m\right)$ but none of the quadrants work, the answer is $m=6$, which corresponds to Quadrant 3 and 4 (tan and cos).

I'm in year 10 just learning complex, so if there are harder methods to this, don't show me.

Comment: If you want something to be in display mode, write `$$...$$` rather than `$...$`.

Comment: Note that $\cos (-x) = \cos x$, and $\sin (-x) = -\sin x$, whatever $x$ is. So the real parts are always equal, and for the imaginary parts, you want $m$ such that $\sin (m\cdot 30^\circ) = -\sin (m\cdot 30^\circ)$. Now, $a = -a$ holds if and only if $a = 0$. So $\sin (m\cdot 30^\circ) = 0$.

Comment: Note that when $m=6$, we have $30m^\circ=180^\circ$.

Comment: Why can't 30m=0, m = 0?

Comment: $m=0$ would work, except that the question asks you to find the smallest *positive* integer $m$, and $0$ is not a positive integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\left(\sqrt{3}+i\right)^m=\left(\sqrt{3}-i\right)^m$$
$$2^m\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right)^m=2^m\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right)^m$$

> [$$e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula)

Using above formula we can write
$$2^m(e^{i\pi/6})^m=2^m(e^{-i\pi/6})^m$$

$$e^{mi\pi/6}=e^{-mi\pi/6}$$

$$e^{2mi\pi/6}=e^{mi\pi/3}=1$$
$$e^{mi\pi/3}=e^{2ik\pi}$$

$$\frac{mi\pi}{3}=2ik\pi$$
$$\frac{m}{3}=2k$$
$$m=6k$$

where $k\in\mathbb Z$